# Print function not being called?

Tags: python

When I run the script, It allows me to input the two user inputs i have in getSales function and getIncrease function, but does my print function at the end seems to do nothing. This is for an extra credit assignment which starts out as just the functions being defined with comments and i have to fill in the rest. Please enlighten me stack overflow community!

```
def main():
    monnthlySales = getSales()
#call to get sales
# This function gets the monthly sales

def getSales():
    monthlySales = float(input('Enter the monthly sales $'))
    salesIncrease = getIncrease() #call to get sales increase
    
    return monthlySales
    
# This function gets the percent of increase in sales
def getIncrease():
   salesIncrease = float(input('Enter percent of sales increase: '))
   salesIncrease = salesIncrease / 100
   return salesIncrease


# This function determines the storeAmount bonus
def storeBonus(monthlySales):
    if monthlySales >= 110000:
        storeAmount = 6000
    elif monthlySales >= 100000:
        storeAmount = 5000
    elif monthlySales >= 90000:
        storeAmount = 4000
    elif monthlySales >= 80000:
        storeAmount = 3000
    else:
        storeAmount = 0
    return storeAmount

# This function determines the empAmount bonus
def empBonus(salesIncrease):
    if salesIncrease >= 0.05:
        empAmmount = 75
    elif salesIncrease >= 0.04:
        empAmmount = 50
    elif salesIncrease >= 0.03:
        empAmmount = 40
    else :
        empAmmount = 0
    return empAmmount

# This function prints the bonus information
def print(storeAmount, empAmount):
    print('The store bonus amount is $', storeAmount)
    print('The employee bonus amount is $', empAmount)
    if storeAmount == 6000 and empAmount == 75:
        print('Congrats! You have reached the highest bonus amounts possible!')
    

main()
```

Comment: Don't name your function `print`, you are overriding the built-in function with the same name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are at least two problems: 1) Calling the function `print` means it will replace the built-in `print` function. 2) There is nothing in your code that actually *calls* the function,  so of course it will not have any visible effect. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. If you need help at this level, you are better served by following a tutorial or getting directed guidance from an instructor.

Comment: And since you're replacing the built-in function, if you do call your function it will get into an infinite recursion.

Comment: Other issues: You assign `salesIncrease`, but never do anything with it. You never call `storeBonus` or `empBonus`.

Answer (score 0):

At least from what I can see, your logic is correct, the only thing that it's necessary to change is to change the word `print` for any kind of function, class, etc. Python have reserved words such as `print`,`return`,`if`, etc. That serve for a specific use.

The only thing that you have to do is to rename your function `def print()` into any word that is not a reserved word.

```
def printBonus(storeAmount, empAmount):
    printBonus('The store bonus amount is $', storeAmount)
    printBonus('The employee bonus amount is $', empAmount)
    if storeAmount == 6000 and empAmount == 75:
        print('Congrats! You have reached the highest bonus amounts possible!')
```

I hope this works for you